# Determining best cutoff value between 2 groups

Tags: continuous-data, group-differences

I have 2 groups (say G1 and G2) and there is a continuous variable (say V) which is significantly different between 2 groups. The mean values for 2 groups are m1 and m2.

I want to determine what is the best cutoff value to discriminate between 2 groups. Is the mean of m1 and m2 (say M) likely to be best cutoff for most of such scenarios? Otherwise, what is proper method to determine best cutoff?

Edit: I am interested in overall accuracy rather than either high sensitivity or high specificity. By overall accuracy I mean following:

```
(number correctly classified) / (total number tested)
```

Comment: If you want to estimate this by using a sample then this is excactly to what a decision stump does (with the appropriate loss function)

Comment: means would be the best cutoff if your classes are balanced and their variance is equal. May be you are looking for something like this: http://mlweb.loria.fr/book/en/optimalhyperplane.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple options:

1. Do a grid search to find the point that discriminates best on your data: just test the accuracy on a large list of points between the means or medians of your data. Sounds like it's a one-dimensional problem so this is feasible.
2. If you prefer a more general model that allows you to use optimization, you can assume distributional forms for the data and then use calculus or gradient descent to find the point that minimizes the overlap between distributions. If you assume normality, you'll get the classic [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis).
3. If you're concerned about prediction on future examples, maybe you're concerned about overfitting, then you might want to do 2 with regularization.

Comment: What about ROC analysis?